# how to upload image in php using base64

Tags: php

hi i can easily upload image in php as follows code

```
            @$file_path = "admin/alumni_image/";
            @$file_name=  basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

            @$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
            if(move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) 
            {
                $response1=array();

                $query = "update alumni set photo = '".$file_name."' where alumni_id = '".$data['alumni_id']."'";
                $query_run=  mysql_query($query);
                echo mysql_error();


             }
```

but now i facing problem when doing same when i got image as base64.

Comment: What is about those `@` that this code seems to love so much?

Comment: @ for no error shown if not used

Comment: Is the question, what to do with it _after uploading_? Since uploading is _uploading_, whether it's base64 encoded or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I've built something like that:

```
        define("UPLOAD_DIR", "images/signatures/");
        $signature = $_POST['signature']; // THIS IS YOUR BASE64 ENCODED STRING
        $signature = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $signature);
        $signature = str_replace(' ', '+', $signature);
        $data = base64_decode($signature);
        $file = UPLOAD_DIR . md5(microtime()) . '.png';
        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: okk  can u also provide how to encode image in base 64 so that i can test it on my side

Comment: here used microtime() and encode with md5.either there is a condition when two image have same name

Comment: no image will have the same name when md5(microtime).

Comment: i use same code for uploading image but when i use same code for multiple image both image with .png extention i found in the folder but second upload image not found ............